# complete a form field from stored data in database by clicking button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a button in create view to check if the user found in table customer or not. if the user found, then textbox field for Name, Location, and Directory number will be written in the same page.

below what i did in view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Tickets", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Badge, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Badge, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })           
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Badge, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Search", "GetInfo", null,  new { badge = Model.Badge })
            </div>
        </div>
```

AND here is my controller method

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetInfo(string badge, Ticket ticket)
    {

        var customers = from c in db.CUSTOMERS select c;
        //if (badge == null)
        ticket.Badge = badge; 
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(badge))

        {
            return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());

        }
        foreach (CUSTOMER c in customers)
        {

            if (badge == c.DIRECTORY_NUMBER)
            {

                ticket.Name = c.NAME;
                ticket.Badge = c.BADGE_NUMBER;
                ticket.Phone = c.BADGE_NUMBER;
                ticket.Location = c.LOCATION;
                return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());

            }
        }
        return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());

    }
```

the error that I got every time is 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
 @Html.ActionLink("Search", "GetInfo", null,  new { badge = Model.Badge })

I think my error is how to pass badge number from view to the controller.

can anyone help me please.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page, you need to use ajax. Your `ActionLink()` method is redirecting and passing the original value of `Badge` (not the edited value) which is presumably `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke did you mean Ajax.ActionLink ?

Comment: Well you could use the (obsolete) `Ajax.ActionLink()` but you would be better of using one of the the `jquery.ajax()` methods.